# Application crashes on iPhone OS 2.2, works fine on 2.1

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, instruments

This is the trace of my app,when I updated my device to 2.2.

any idea to get rid of this leak? because I think that's the culprit who keep crashing my application.
This is trace when I run my application in os2.2,see the image which show the part which might be generating leak,and if you can give me some hints to resolve it, will be greatly appreciated.

[alt text http://origindata.wapfly.com.au/extra/Picture%204.png](http://origindata.wapfly.com.au/extra/Picture%204.png)

[alt text http://origindata.wapfly.com.au/extra/Picture%203.png](http://origindata.wapfly.com.au/extra/Picture%203.png)
This is trace when I run my application in os2.1.it's very wired issue.
[alt text http://origindata.wapfly.com.au/extra/Picture%205.png](http://origindata.wapfly.com.au/extra/Picture%205.png)

Answer (score 1):

That trace is rather meaningless without access to the code.  My suggestion would be to download and install the Clang Static Analyzer and run your code against it to determine where the leak exists.  It can be found at http://clang.llvm.org/StaticAnalysis.html - to use it, copy the contents of the .tar.gz file to /usr/bin then cd to your Xcode project and run `scan-build xcodebuild`. At which point you'll be given output that directs you to copy and pate a line that resembles `scan-view /tmp/logs/...`  That should give you some indication.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the "View" button in the upper right of Instruments and choose "Extended Detail" then click the line item as you have selected above then click the details in the Extended Details right hand side column and it will open up to the line of code at fault in XCode